# Let $b,p \in \mathbb{R}$, $p>0$. Find the distance from the point $(0,b)$ to the curve $x^2-4py=0$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $b,p \in \mathbb{R}$, $p>0$. Find the distance from the point $(0,b)$ to the curve $x^2-4py=0$.

The given curve can be identified by a parabola and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the distance  from a point $P$ to set $A$ is $$inf_{Q \in A}d(P,Q)$$ where $d$ is the euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$. My idea is to find a function in terms of the parabola $x^2-4py=0$ lets say $P(x)=(x, ?)$ leading to calculate the values $x$ and $b$ where $d(x)=d(b,P(x))$ takes its minimum values.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to minimize the distance $$\sqrt{(0-x)^2+(b-y)^2}$$ between $(0,b)$ and the parabola consisting of points $(x,y)$. You can substitute in $y=\frac{x^2}{4p}$ since $p>0$ and then the above distance is just a function of $x$ (which you can find the minimum of with routine calculus). In fact, you can omit the square root when doing the minimizing calculations (since the distance is minimized simultaneously with the square distance).

Comment: Thanks! But the calculations to minimum solution 
to solvee the equation  you proposed are nightmarish @Dave

Comment: They shouldn't be too bad: the above square distance is a quartic in $x$, so the derivative is a cubic which will be divisible by $x$, so it really boils down to solving a quadratic for the other roots of the first derivative (look to the quadratic formula!).

Answer (score 1):

By the method of Lagrange multipliers:

Let $\displaystyle L=x^2+(b-y)^2 - \lambda (x^2 -4py)$.

$\displaystyle 0=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = x-\lambda$

$\displaystyle 0=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = b - y + 2p \lambda$

$\displaystyle 0= -\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = x^2-4py$

Combine the first two equations to get a linear relation between $x$ and $y$ and substitute into the third equation.  Then use the quadratic formula or complete-the-square.

Comment: Thanks! I think $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}$ is not well calculated as    $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}= -x^2+4py$. Also what is the realtion you mention between $x$ and $y$?? @mjw

Comment: Nice catch.  Fixed the typo in the $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}$ equation.  As you notice, this just gives back the equation of the constraining curve in the problem formulation.

Comment: I just meant that we can replace $\lambda$ in the second (partial differential) equation by $x$ so that $0=b-y+ 2px$.  This is a line.  Now we can solve for either $x$ or $y$ in terms of the other variable and plug this into the equation for the parabola.  Either way we get a quadratic equation (in $x$ or in $y$).